# converting word into other word keeping the original format

Tags: python, python-3.x

def translate(string, translations):

```
'''
>>> translations = {'he':'she', 'brother':'sister'}
>>> translate('he', translations)
'she'
>>> translate('HE', translations)
'SHE'
>>> translate('He', translations)
'She'
>>> translate('brother', translations)
'sister'
>>> translate('my', translations)
'my'
'''
```

I have inputs like this.  I used **translations.get(string)** to get he and sister and it worked well.  But the thing is that I cant convert the strings to 'She' or 'sHe' (in the original format).
How to do it in Python?

Comment: You can use `str.lower()`/`str.title()` as per requirement

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to either have a bigger dictionary, case sensitive, or your translate function is going to have to be modified to:

1. Detect the case of the original word or phrase, *all lower, all upper, sentence or title.*
2. Look up the translation *case insensitive*
3. Re-case the translated text to match the original.

**But** with some languages you will still have some issues, e.g.: in some languages all caps includes some lower case letters sometimes or capitalise the second letter rather than the first *such as d' as a prefix would always be lower case* or have different capitalisation rules, *in SI units UK capitalisation rules say that if the unit is named after a person it should always be capitalise but other countries do this differently.*

Answer (score 1):

Just as you have a data structure of translations, we can create a data structure of case tests and corrections:

```
def iscapitalized(s):
    return s and s[0].isupper() and s[1:].islower()

def translate(string, translations):
    translation = translations.get(string.lower(), string)

    for test, correction in corrections.items():
            if test(string):
                translation = correction(translation)
                break

    return translation

translations = {'he': 'she', 'brother': 'sister'}

corrections = {str.isupper: str.upper, str.islower: str.lower, iscapitalized: str.capitalize}

print(translate('he', translations))
print(translate('HE', translations))
print(translate('He', translations))
print(translate('brother', translations))
print(translate('my', translations))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
she
SHE
She
sister
my
>
```